# Transitions and fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, transition

For my app's UI, I use `Transition`s and `Fragment`s. In the `onCreateView` function of my first `Fragment`, I launch a `Transition` to change the display from a first `Scene` to a second `Scene`. Afterwards, when I click on a `Button`, I start another `Transition` to show some kind of "splashscreen" represented by a third `Scene` and, in it's `onTransactionEnd`, I try to change the `Fragment` with `myView.postDelayed(new myRunnableForChangingFragment(),1000)`.

In debug mode, I see my `Runnable` is correctly launched, but the new `Fragment` doesn't replace the first one... Nevertheless, something did happen : I have to click two times on the back button to return to my first `Fragment`. In fact, it seems the `Fragment` is activated but not visible...

Any idea about how I could fix that?

As asked in the first comment, here's the code I use to change the `Fragment`:

```
    fragment=new mySecondFragment();
    transaction=getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.Conteneur, fragment,"Fragment tag");
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
```

I can add that this code launched from outside the `onTransitionEnd` works perfectly.

The xml file for the "container" :

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>    android:id="@+id/Conteneur"
>    android:orientation="vertical"
>    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>    android:layout_height="fill_parent">     
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

The xml file for the first and the second scene (the only difference ; buttons are set invisible in code in the first one) :

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/TitreJeux"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="center"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/MargeVerticaleBoutonsInterfaceJeux"
>     android:lines="1"
>     android:text="@string/app_name"
>     android:textColor="#FFFF00"
>     android:textSize="35sp"
>     android:textStyle="bold"
>     android:typeface="serif"/>
>
> <vd63.jeux.JeuAnimationRapide.BoutonInterface
>     android:id="@+id/BoutonOptions"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="0dp"
>     android:layout_gravity="center"
>     android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/MargeVerticaleBoutonsInterfaceJeux"
>     android:layout_weight="1"
>     android:background="@drawable/bouton_jouer"
>     android:text="@string/BoutonOptions"
>     android:textColor="@color/CouleurTexteBoutons"
>     android:textSize="25sp"
>     android:typeface="serif"/>
> ```

The xml fle for the "splash" scene :

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>           xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>           android:id="@+id/EcranChargement"
>           android:orientation="vertical"
>           android:gravity="center"
>           android:background="@drawable/fond_interface"
>           android:layout_width="match_parent"
>           android:layout_height="match_parent"
>           tools:context=".JeuAnimationRapide">
>
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/VD63"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:src="@drawable/vd63"/>
>
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/Chargement"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:src="@drawable/chargement"/>
> ```

I transition from scene one (button invisible,simple `Slide`) to scene 2 then back to scene 1 (`Slide` again) then to the "splash" scene (with a `Fade` transition).

Comment: Would please share the FragmentTransaction code ?

Comment: OK, problem solved! I was messing up with the different views and containers...

Answer (score 1):

When you switch from fragment one to fragment two use below code It works for me I hope it will help you.

```
Fragment fragment = SearchActivity.newInstance(context);
String tag = fragment.toString();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.addToBackStack(tag)       
.replace(R.id.fragment, new SearchActivity())
.commit();
```

Use addToBackStack when you want to come back to this fragment again on backpress otherwise you don't need to add addTobackstack